# "In data (A) : data set (A) not found" (but > read.table(A) is ok)

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-analysis, bioinformatics

According to (Mfuzz (clustering software))
http://
127.0.0.1:14087/library/utils/html/data.html

I want to create `data(...)` from my file which is .txt. 
By using commands: `read.table()`, `head()`, `summary()` << the data can print out but when I use `data()`, the warning appears as below

```
> exprsFile <- "C:/Users/admin/Documents/CIP.txt"
> read.table(exprsFile)
```

^this is ok, my all file data print out

```
> data(read.table(exprsFile))
Warning message:
In data(read.table(exprsFile)) : data set ‘read.table(exprsFile)’ not found
```

Also,

```
> load(read.table(exprsFile))
Error in load(read.table(exprsFile)) : bad 'file' argument
```

How to fix this problem for making data()?
Thank you very much

Comment: `data<-read.table(exprsFile)`;`head(data)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Well.. I may understand wrong but I don't want to store read.table... in "data". I want to use function data() which in parenthesis is read.table(exprsFile)

Thank you very much

Comment: From `?data`: "data() was originally intended to allow users to load datasets from packages for use in their examples, and as such it loaded the datasets into the workspace .GlobalEnv.". Create a package with your dataset and load it using `data`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're trying to do. But can you check if this works:

```
data<- function(a){
    d<-a
    return(d)}
```

Then:

```
data(read.table(exprsFile))
```